# PHP SimpleHtmlDom xpath

Tags: php, xpath, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the contents of the node in the webpage I am parsing. Here is my code:

```
include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
// get DOM from URL or file
$feedUrl = "http://www.yellowpages.com/md/cpa-tax?menu_search=false&page=1&refinements%5Bfacet_clicked%5D=HeadingText&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Accountants-Certified+Public&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation-Business";
$html = file_get_html($feedUrl);
$xpath = "/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/h3[1]/div[1]/a[1]";
foreach($html->find($xpath) as $e) 
    echo $e->title . '<br>';
```

In this example, I am trying to get the name "Tax Experience CPA, Inc" from the webpage. The issue is the array returned by find($xpath) is always empty. When I open Google Chrome and search for the node with that xpath, I am able to exactly find the node I want. But this is not working in my code. There must be an issue with the path I am using, but I can't figure out what it is. I have searched and searched but I haven't been able to find what I am doing wrong.
Please help.

Comment: Best way to find xpath is firefox firebug.  Without seeing the exact html dom, there is no way to help.

Comment: I included the webpage with the html dom in my original post.

Comment: yes, sorry, I commented so quick and then realized..  checking it out now.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. I installed firebug and looked up the xpath with firebug. The path seems to be the same as what I have (/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/a/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/h3/div/a) except I added the [1] to my first child div, a, and h3 elements. I tried without the [1], that does not work either. Finding the path with firebug was much easier than what I originally did (manually find the path).

Comment: When you added the [1] did you add the `,0`, like: `$html->find("/html/body/div[1]/p[1]", 0);` (just example).  Also, for testing purposes, just as a suggestion for simplicity and/or readability, maybe remove the foreach loop around `$html->find()`  and just print_r or var_dump it.

Comment: I did try adding the ,0. That did not work unfortunately. I removed the foreach loop and var_dump-ed the $html->find()->title. The result was "NULL" echo-ed out to the browser. For some reason the following code does work and finds all the name/title elements on the page: foreach ($html->find("h3/div/a") as $e) 
  echo $e->title . '<br>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website has lot of nodes with ids and classes, use them to create a shorter simpler xpath expression to retrieve what you want !

Here's a working code for you:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$feedUrl = "http://www.yellowpages.com/md/cpa-tax?menu_search=false&page=1&refinements%5Bfacet_clicked%5D=HeadingText&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Accountants-Certified+Public&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation-Business";

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load_file($feedUrl);

// Find all anchors
$anchors = $html->find("//div[@class='srp-business-name']/a");

// Display all titles
foreach($anchors as $a) 
    echo $a->title . '<br>';
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tax Experience CPA Inc
Bernice Hassan CPA Accounting & Tax Services
Begosh Tax Service CPA
At-Home CPA Tax Service
CPA Financial & Tax Service
My Tax CPA
...
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y2k-7uc)

### EDIT:

Here's a modified code grabbing the title and the phone number from each "element/div".

Notice that `find("...", $index)` returns one element specified by `$index` (Nth element starting from 0), and returns an array of elements if `$index` is not set...

```
$feedUrl = "http://www.yellowpages.com/md/cpa-tax?menu_search=false&page=1&refinements%5Bfacet_clicked%5D=HeadingText&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Accountants-Certified+Public&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation-Business";

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load_file($feedUrl);

// Find all elements
$divs = $html->find('div.business-container-inner');

// loop through all elements and display the useful parts
foreach($divs as $div) {
    $title = $div->find('div.srp-business-name a', 0)->title;

    $phone = $div->find('span.business-phone', 0)->plaintext;

    echo $title ." - ". $phone . "<br>";
}

// Clear DOM object
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kt9-smz)

Comment: If I want to find the respective phone number for each business on the same webpage, how would I go about selecting the business name and then the business' respective phone number? Could I select the child phone number element of the parent and the name element of the parent? What would that code look like?

Comment: @JohnS, answer updated... Please feel free to post a new question (if you have any) to not overload this one :)

Comment: @JohnS, Glad I helped... Don't forget to delete your other duplicated question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, You should try this.

```
include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$feedUrl = "http://www.yellowpages.com/md/cpa-tax?menu_search=false&page=1&refinements%5Bfacet_clicked%5D=HeadingText&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Accountants-Certified+Public&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation&refinements%5Bheadingtext%5D%5B%5D=Tax+Return+Preparation-Business";

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($feedUrl);
$xpath = ".srp-business-name a";
foreach($html->find($xpath) as $e) 
    echo $e->title . '<br>';
```